# select from is giving me error messages

Tags: sql, sql-server

Both of the following gave me the error messages `Invalid object` but they are the correct names. Any Idea what the problem may be?

```
select * from TrainingDB.FileTables.employes
```

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'TrainingDB.FileTables.employes'.

```
select * from employes
```

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'employes'.

Im useing 2014 dev edition

Update 
I disconnected, reconnected a started a new query by right clicking on TrainingDB this time rather than the main button for new query witch I had been doing before employes is coming up on the intellisense now and select * from employes now works.

Thank you all of you I probably would have been stuck for hours longer without your help.

Comment: Make sure you are connected to correct server and names may be case sensitive

Comment: check the spelling. Employees is with 2 e's

Comment: I spelt it like that when I made the table I can rename table and query. But they already match so it wouldn't make it work. I copied the table name from the rename box to make sure it was the same.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are executing the query on the wrong server. So you can check the server on which you are executing the query.(*Assuming that the database and table name which you mentioned in the question is correct.*)

Comment: Not likely, it this was true `select * from TrainingDB.FileTables.employes` would work. Probably table name is incorrect.

Comment: @Yosi:- Yes but see the question line `Invalid object but they are the correct names.` so I dont think that table name is wrong, but I assumed if OP is executing `select      * 
from employes` query in the correct database and if it is not working then most likely the problem is that it may be executed on the wrong server

Comment: The table name is definitely correct I spelt it incorrectly when I made the table but I copied that spelling to the query to be sure they matched. Im also getting the same message for all other tables I've tried it with.

Comment: I disconnected, reconnected a started a new query by right clicking on TrainingDB  this time rather than the main button for new query witch I had been doing before employes  is coming up on the intellisense now and select * from employes now works

Comment: @douglasalderman:- Looks like you were working on a disconnected environment. And restarting it worked for you. !

Answer (score 1):

Check your db tables name spelling. and also check in which database you are using. You can check by

```
  DatabaseName.dbo.tablename
```

you also should use  Intellisense in sql server management studio. For avoiding these issue. You could down load it there [dbforge-sqlcomplete](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/)

Comment: I think i'm using Intellisense I get a list of possible options when I start typing only non of my tables are on the list.

Comment: The intellisense shows has a table I made when I was using the free 2008 version but nothing I made that I can see on my server .

Comment: have you checked in the object explorer that your table exists in that database manually.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages are straight. The engine don't found that table in that local PERIOD.

In doubt if the object exits you can try this snippet:

```
use TrainingDB

GO

declare
 @columnName nvarchar(128) = N'MyColumnName'
,@tableName nvarchar(128) = N'employes'
,@schemaName nvarchar(128) = N'FileTables'


    select su.name, so.name--, sc.name
    from sys.sysusers su
    join sys.sysobjects so on so.uid = su.uid
--  join sys.syscolumns sc on sc.id = so.id
    where so.xtype = N'U'
    and su.name = @schemaName
    and so.name = @tableName
--  and sc.name = @columnName
```

As you can see this can be used to test if schema, table and if you remove comments even the column exists.

If you still cannot find the object the previous answers already points a few motives: wrong server, wrong database, wrong database version (where the table is missing), collation making object names case sensitive, mispelling, lack of permission, etc.

Comment: So the objects don't exists where you are looking for. Look in another place os look for another object (name). Also read the possible motives I listed and good luck